# Script hangs when executing in windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Hello I have a batch file that is used to move text file from on directory to another. The problem is that when there is a text file larger then 7 MB the scrip hangs and freezes the process, which leads to manually force the batch to end.

Why does this bat hang when it moves larger files then 7mb?. How can I solve this to let it move any size text file?

Thank you in advance for your help.

PS.   TYPE was used because the original file is in ANSI/UNIX format and the only way we found to convert it to ANSI/PC was using TYPE.

```
cd /d  "c:\users\you\"
for %%i in (*.txt) do (
  echo processing %%i
  TYPE "%%i" | MORE /P > "c:\temp\%%i"
  del "%%i"
)
```

Comment: Q: Why use `TYPE "%%i" | MORE /P > foo` instead of `move`?

Comment: @paulsm4 read the PS

Comment: It seems that you're using `more` to do the newline expansion, not `type`.  Is there any difference if you take `type` out of the picture?  `more /p "%%i" > "c:\temp\%%i"`

Comment: It's the `more` that is converting the file, not the `type`.  Unfortunately it is probably also the `more` that is stopping after a certain number of lines (which is after all what it is for).

Comment: I used more  `/p "%%i" > "c:\temp\%%i" ` instead but im still getting the hung state, it seems to be the MORE. Is there anyway to get around this?

Comment: If it was me, I'd just throw it out and write a small python script. You could also probably do it in PowerShell if you can't install python.

Comment: @Blorgbeard throwing it out is not an option, I just need to figure out how to modify that existing script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of the `more` command is to present only one page worth of text at a time.  When the output device is not a console, the effective page length is very long but not infinite - it will still pause after writing 65534 lines.

Instead, try this:

```
(for /F "delims=" %%L in (%%i) do @echo %%L) > "c:\temp\%%i"
```

Command line breakdown:

`for /F` - read the contents of a file

`"delims="` - don't treat spaces or tabs as delimeters

`%%L` - the variable (same as the `%%i` in the `for` command from your original script)

`%%i` - the file to read

`@echo` - writes the variable to standard output

`( ) > file.txt` - redirects standard output to the destination file

Comment: Wow! It work. Could you explain what you put in the line of code?

Comment: sorry to ask , im actually beginning to program and discover this world.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `"delims="` without the colon?

Comment: What is the difference @paddy?

Comment: You are telling it to use `:` as a delimiter, so if any line in the source file contains a colon, then only the characters up until the first colon will be available in `%%L`.

Comment: What does the /F and %%L mean?

Comment: The online help is `for /?`